# AWS Lambda Scheduled One Time Tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I’m working on figuring out the best way to have Lambda run one time tasks at a given time.

The system I’m envisioning will basically have events that will need to be sent out, either as soon as the event is received/created, at a specific time, or as a recurring action. And I’d like to use AWS as much as possible for this, due to the scalable nature.

My original idea was to have a AWS SQS queue for events to send. Then I’d have a DynamoDB table for future events. I’d also have two AWS Lambda functions, one setup to run on a cron job every few minutes to take the events that are scheduled in the next 15 minutes or so from the DynamoDB table and put them into that AWS SQS queue with a Message Timer setup to delay the message from being visible for that given time. The second Lambda function would be setup and have a trigger to be run from that AWS SQS queue. This function would be responsible for actually sending the event out.

From there I could either add the event to the SQS queue (with or without a message timer) if it’s gonna need to be sent out within the next 15 minutes. Or add it to the DynamoDB table if it’s gonna need to be sent out in the future (beyond 15 minutes).

The biggest problem I just figured out is that [AWS SQS FIFO queues doesn’t support Message Timers on individual messages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-timers.html). I need a FIFO queue because I need to prevent these events from being sent out multiple times, or triggering my second Lambda function twice.

I've also looked into the AWS Lambda cron jobs, and although you can schedule invocations every say 5 minutes, I don't think this is what I'm looking for because I'm looking more for scheduling a 1 time invocation in the future, and having that be scalable. So I don't think this is what I'm looking for.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this, since it doesn’t look like Amazon SQS Message Timers will work for what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered Step Function? You could create a [wait state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-wait-state.html) before invoking the lambda.

Comment: I don't think this will work since I can't find a way to pass in a custom value into that `Timestamp` parameter.